# Existence results for Lagrangian solutions to the Incompressible Euler Equation?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fluid-dynamics, hamiltonian-mechanics, navier-stokes

It is known that if a function (which we shall call the lagrangian flow, or lagrangian trajectory) $$X:(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^3 \times [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^3$$ with $X \in H^1_t$ (i.e. has weak time derivatives $v=\partial_tX \in L^2((\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^3\times [0,T])$) minimises the energy lagrangian $$L[X]=\int_{(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^3 \times [0,T]} v^2$$ subject to $X(\cdot,0),X(\cdot,T)$ fixed, and $X(\cdot,t)$ being a $\textbf{volume preserving}$ diffeomorphism of $(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^3$ for each $t$,

then $u(\cdot,t)=v(\cdot,t) \circ X(\cdot,t)^{-1}$ is a weak solution to the incompressible Euler equation $$\dot{u} + \nabla \cdot (uu) = \nabla p, \nabla \cdot u = 0$$ in a distributional sense.

My question is about existence results once $X(\cdot,0),X(T,\cdot)$ are fixed, and depends on what we mean by diffeomorphisms:

1. if we require $X(0,t)$ to be $C^{\infty}$ volume preserving diffeomorphisms for each $t$, can we guarantee the existence of a minimiser?
2. if we require $X(0,t)$ to be $C^1$ volume preserving diffeomorphisms for each $t$, again, can we guarantee the existence of a minimser?
3. I expect both of the above answers are no or at least unknown, since I've found no mention of them in the literature I've read. The case I'm therefore really interested in is when by 'diffeomorphism' we only require that $$X(\cdot,t) \text{  is bijective, and measure preserving}$$ Correct me if I'm wrong but the above theory still holds even in this loose definition. Can we now, i.e. in the loosest sense, get existence of minimisers? Perhaps with some conditions on $X(\cdot,0)$ and $X(\cdot,T)$? Anything known, perhaps some papers, about this case would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest readong the following three classical references: [Shnirelman (1997). On the nonuniqueness of weak solution of the Euler equation, CPAM, 50(12)] for the nonexistence of minimizers, [Brenier (1989) The least action principle and the related concept of generalized flows for incompressible perfect fluids. Journal AMS 2(2)] for existence of generalized solutions, and finally [Ebin Marsden (1970) Groups of diffeomorphisms and the notion of an incompressible fluid. Ann. of Math. (2) 92] for existence of regular solutions with endpoints close to each other.